# OOP PHP connect and select functions

Tags: php, mysql, oop

Hey guys i've come across the following problem. I have a database class with a fully working connect function, I am now wanting to use this myconn variable in my other class News. I keep getting error messages whichever way i go around it. One of the messages is;

Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\Users\PC\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\class.News.php on line 10

I am new to OOP so any help will be greatly appreciated.

class.Database

```
<?php

class Database{

private $db_host = 'localhost'; 
private $db_user = 'c3337015'; 
private $db_pass = 'c3337015'; 
private $db_name = 'iitb'; 
public $myconn;

public function connect(){

if(!isset($this->myconn)){

$this->myconn = mysqli_connect($this->db_host,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass,$this->db_name);

if($this->myconn){
    echo "connected"; // echoing just for testing purposes
    return true; 
}else{
echo "failed";
return false; 
}}else{
echo "already connected";
return false; 
}
 }

public function disconnect()
{
if(isset($this->myconn))
{
    if(mysqli_close($this->myconn))
    {
        $this->myconn = false; 
        echo "connection closed";
        return true; 
    }
    else
    {
    echo "failed to close connection";
        return false; 
    }
}else{
    echo "no connection prescent";
}
}

}
```

class.News

```
<?php
require_once('class.Database.php');
class News extends Database{

function getNews(){

$me = new Database();
$me->connect();
// HOW DO I USE THE MYCONN VARIABLE AS DEFINED IN CLASS.DATABASE
$stmt = $this->myconn->prepare(" SELECT * FROM news ");

//the rest of the $stmt etc etc....

}

}
```

Comment: Thats the strangest mix of `OOP` and `procedural` programming .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your database class in your other class, then it's other type of dependency. You class shouldn't extend database class, because it does not.

You should just include your database class as you already did and just use it.

Then you should use it like this (based on code you provided):

```
$me = new Database();
$me->connect();
$stmt = $me->myconn->prepare(" SELECT * FROM news ");
```

But you should probably read some paper on OOP before proceeding, because you do not use this paradigm correctly.

Comment: thanks for the help, i use a lot of YouTube tutorials but i find that OOP is so hard to get started with, a lot of examples out there are very irrelevant.

Comment: I recommend this book to anyone interested in this topic: "Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software" by Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson and John Vlissides. You might find some answers there.